# Combinatorics Problem How many ways to sit?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are 4 boys and 4 girls. They want to sitting in a row. How many ways to sit, if given conditions **there is no** 2 boys or 2 girls sitting next to each other?

To answer this question, I use complement rule.

Number ways to sit if no condition: $8!$.

Now I confused to determine number ways to sit if 2 boys and 2 girls sitting next to each other. Is it right we have to arrange

(B1,B2)(B3,B4)(G1,G2)(G3,G4)?

Number of ways to arrange B1,B2,B3,B4 and G1,G2,G3,G4 is $4!\times 4!$
Number of ways to arrange (B1,B2)(B3,B4)(G1,G2)(G3,G4) is $4!$
So we have number ways to sit if 2 boys and 2 girls sitting next to each other is $(4!)^3$.

So, the answer is $8!-(4!)^3$. Is it right answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no pair of boys or girls sit next to each other, then they must alternate.

Pick which gender sits in the leftmost seat $(2)$. Then choose the order of the four boys $(4!)$ and the order of the four girls $(4!)$.

So $2 \cdot 4!^2 = 1152$ ways.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not right answer. There are many more ways in which two boys or two girls sit next to each other, for example like $$BGGBGBGB$$
Now, to count the required number of ways, arrange the four girls in $4!$ ways. There are $3$ gaps created between them, as follows: $$G\_G\_G\_G$$
If a gap contains no boy, that is a problem because two girls will then have to sit together. Hence, all of these gaps contains boys, the fourth boy will either sit before first girl or after last girl. So, required configurations are $$BGBGBGBG$$
$$GBGBGBGB$$
Number of arrangements in both of them is $4!\times 4!$, so answer is $2\times 4!\times4! = 1152.$

Answer (score 1):

If no two boys or two girls are sitting next to each other, there are two cases:

1. They are arranged as BGBGBGBG

This means there are (4!)^2 possibilities for this case.

2. They are are arranged as GBGBGBGB

This means that there are once again (4!)^2 possibilities.

Hence, all together there are 2*(4!)^2 possibilities or 1152 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

No. There many more ways in which it is true that either two boys or two girls sit next to each other. for example:

$BBGBGGBG$

Or

$GGGBBGBB$

Or ....

In fact, for this problem, it is really just much easier to directly consider all the ways in which there are no two boys or girls sitting next to each other. Think about it: It's not hard. I am sure you can figure it out!